# What does it mean by: Taylor series of $f(1+x)$ converges to $f(1+x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have $f(1)=0$ and $f'(x)=1/x$. Consider Taylor series of $f(1+x)$ centered at $x=0$, I need to show that it converges to $f(1+x)$.

I got $f(1+x) = \sum (-1)^{n}*x$. 
I don't know what to do from here and I am not sure what "Taylor series of $f(1+x)$ converges to $f(1+x)$" means.

Comment: Write down the Taylor series of order $N$ $T_N(x)$ for $f(1+x) = \log(1+x)$ about $x=0$ ($T_N(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{f^{(n)}(1)x^n}{n!}$). Then use [Taylor's theorem with the remainder term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) to show that the Taylor series for $f(1+x)$ converges to $\log(1+x)$ (if $|x| <1 $) when $N\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> I got $f(1+x) = \sum (-1)^{n}\cdot x$.

I am guessing that is not what you have done. From what you know about $f(1+x)$, you can build a *related* series, known as the Taylor series centered at $0$ (or Maclaurin series for short). If you do this correctly, you get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$ But you do not yet have the right to say that $f(1+x)$ *equals* this series. In fact it doesn't. But for $x$-values in the appropriate window, which turns out to be $(-1,1]$, this series does converge to the same value that $f(1+x)$ takes. This is what you are being asked to prove: that for $x\in(-1,1]$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ converges to $f(1+x)$. Once we all understand this we can be loose and say $f(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ for $x\in(-1,1]$.

The way to prove such things is to understand and use [Taylor's inequality](https://www.google.com/search?q=taylor%27s+inequality).

Comment: Can you help with little more? I am not understanding it at all. Can you show me little more steps to get correct function?

Comment: Ok, I was stupid. I got the right summation.